# How to choose what JPanel in a split pane is resized when the entire app. is resized?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, jsplitpane

So I am programming an application using Java Swing, and I am wondering how to make it so that when the entire application gets resized only certain panels get resized in various ways. Take a look at the two pictures below:

[image: JavaSwing before resize]
[image: JavaSwing after resize]

I have three vertical panels as you can see. Now when the application's height is extended all three panels heights should increase also, that works fine. However when the width is increased I want it so that only the middle panel's (which will be the "workspace") width is increased. Instead, as you can see, the last-to-be-added third panel on the right is the only one whose width increases.

How do I go about to make it so that only the middle `JPanel` stretches & shrinks as the entire window is resized in the x axis? Also, later I would like to make it so that this workspace panel isn't always going to be in the middle; as the user can move the other two panels around to customize the app to their own taste, such as to make the two other panels stacked up on top of each other to the left while the workspace is on the right. However regardless of where it is I want the workspace panel to be the one the resizes, how do I do that?

Comment: I bet you can use a `WindowListener` and on I think the `windowResized()` method, select your `middle panel` and resize it accordingly. I'm not sure if you can get the old width (store it?) or you can do `middlepanel.setWidth(window.getWidth() - leftpanel.getWidth() - rightpanel.getWidth());`

Comment: See also [How to create great screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  That would have made it obvious that you are referring to panels in a (couple of) **`JTabbedPane`** components!

Comment: Admitting you use the Netbeans GUI Builder might get you shot around these parts, but in the offchance you are actually using it, I made a handy YouTube video once to show what I've learned: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1hPFh_UIFjc.

Comment: To add: since making that video, Netbeans has made a lot of improvements to the GUI Builder that give hand-coded layout managers a real run for their money. So it's even better now than it was then.

Comment: Oops! By *" .. **`JTabbedPane`** components!"* I meant **`JSplitPane`.**

Comment: You seem to have accepted answers to only 2 of your last 10 questions.  Please visit your profile, look up those questions, and see if you can accept an answer (or alternately delete the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to call [`setResizeWeight(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setResizeWeight-double-) on the correct split pane with the appropriate value.  E.G.

[image: Two split panes at minimum size]

[image: Two split panes with extra width]

[image: Two split panes with extra width & height]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class DualingSplitPanes {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    DualingSplitPanes() {
        initUI();
    }

    protected final void addPanelsToUi(JPanel p1, JPanel p2, JPanel p3) {
        JSplitPane sp1 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, p1, p2);
        JSplitPane sp2 = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, sp1, p3);
        sp2.setResizeWeight(1);

        ui.add(sp2);
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        JPanel treeContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.setVisibleRowCount(5);
        for (int i=tree.getVisibleRowCount()-1; i>-1; i--) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
        treeContainer.add(new JScrollPane(tree));

        JPanel workSpaceContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
        workSpaceContainer.add(new JTextArea(5, 10));

        JPanel searchContainer = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        searchContainer.add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea(5, 10)));

        addPanelsToUi(treeContainer, workSpaceContainer, searchContainer);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                DualingSplitPanes o = new DualingSplitPanes();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make the constrains of the boxes so they are dependent of their corresponding side of the window.

So the left pane is X pixels from the left, and the right pane is Y pixels from the right, and then the middle one is constrained by having the left side X+ from the left, and the right side Y+ from the right.

This works as long as you don't resize the window too small (because then the elements get too big).